# How to generate transaction history from all addresses that are part of common xpub/ypub without having the xpub/ypub?

Tags: transactions, xpub

I have 20 addresses generated  which are part of a common xpub/ypub. I want to create a combined transaction history of all addresses similar to that of how trezor has the export CSV function. I understand that trezor generates it from the xpub, but in my case I have the addresses but not the xpub.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a watch-only wallet in bitcoin core
2. Add the addresses using [importaddress](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/importaddress/) or [importmulti](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/importmulti/). I imported one address for testing: `importaddres tb1qpax3dzmat0qffp3pgkmnmue4tps0xglru65crt "test1" false`
3. Rescan blockchain. I did `rescanblockchain 1810000 1896271` for testing
4. [List Transactions for the addresses](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/listtransactions/).

I get the below results:

```
 
[
  {
    "involvesWatchonly": true,
    "address": "tb1qpax3dzmat0qffp3pgkmnmue4tps0xglru65crt",
    "category": "receive",
    "amount": 0.01200000,
    "label": "test1",
    "vout": 1,
    "confirmations": 57879,
    "blockhash": "000000006ff7a6de9ddedfa8f3dec502e0740b4e19bf9d60091711f442a383fd",
    "blockheight": 1838397,
    "blockindex": 16,
    "blocktime": 1602028580,
    "txid": "98fe1985b800b87a5196c2d1d01980a9930532b0f9b8c5488bfde273cf9b1b01",
    "walletconflicts": [
    ],
    "time": 1602028580,
    "timereceived": 1607228610,
    "bip125-replaceable": "no"
  },
  {
    "involvesWatchonly": true,
    "address": "tb1qj5q83vcsldetj6krhv0jgwexff2vj6xfmd8az6",
    "category": "send",
    "amount": -0.01000000,
    "vout": 1,
    "fee": -0.00000282,
    "confirmations": 4,
    "blockhash": "0000000097539dce940bacac2da89704645862ab878bbb1aa832d5fd3b65c91f",
    "blockheight": 1896272,
    "blockindex": 69,
    "blocktime": 1607229053,
    "txid": "06ff26b56ac6636326cb2f25b6434243a755e2fd2574808271a88ca23fc05b54",
    "walletconflicts": [
    ],
    "time": 1607228776,
    "timereceived": 1607228776,
    "bip125-replaceable": "no",
    "abandoned": false
  },
  {
    "involvesWatchonly": true,
    "address": "tb1qjd4cnkp0zz4dhl2383tugl54dd9eryteya7yjv",
    "category": "send",
    "amount": -0.00199718,
    "vout": 0,
    "fee": -0.00000282,
    "confirmations": 4,
    "blockhash": "0000000097539dce940bacac2da89704645862ab878bbb1aa832d5fd3b65c91f",
    "blockheight": 1896272,
    "blockindex": 69,
    "blocktime": 1607229053,
    "txid": "06ff26b56ac6636326cb2f25b6434243a755e2fd2574808271a88ca23fc05b54",
    "walletconflicts": [
    ],
    "time": 1607228776,
    "timereceived": 1607228776,
    "bip125-replaceable": "no",
    "abandoned": false
  }
]
```

Results are in JSON format according to my understanding, you can convert them to CSV using one of the available options depending on OS or programming language you prefer to use. Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507615/parse-json-data-using-jq-and-convert-into-csv